# Python3 print() Vs Python2 print

Tags: python, stdout

While working on a buffer overflow exploit I found something really strange. I have successfully found that I need to provide 32 characters before the proper address I want to jump to and that the proper address is `0x08048a37`. When I executed

```
python -c "print '-'*32+'\x37\x8a\x04\x08'" | ./MyExecutable
```

the exploit resulted in a success. But, when I tried:

```
python3 -c "print('-'*32+'\x37\x8a\x04\x08')" | ./MyExecutable
```

it didn't. The executable simply resulted in a Segmentation Fault without jumping to the desired address. In fact, executing

```
python -c "print '-'*32+'\x37\x8a\x04\x08'"
```

and

```
python3 -c "print('-'*32+'\x37\x8a\x04\x08')"
```

results in two different output on the console. The characters are, of course, not readable but they're visually different.

I wonder why is this happening?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Python 2 code writes *bytes*, the Python 3 code writes *text* that is then encoded to bytes. The latter will thus not write the same output; it depends on the codec configured for your pipe.

In Python 3, write bytes to the `sys.stdout.buffer` object instead:

```
python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'-'*32+b'\x37\x8a\x04\x08')"
```

You may want to manually add the `\n` newline that `print` would add.

`sys.stdout` is a [`io.TextIOBase` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase), encoding data written to it to a given codec (usually based on your locale, but when using a pipe, often defaulting to ASCII), before passing it on to the underlying buffer object. The [`TextIOBase.buffer` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer) gives you direct access to the underlying [`BufferedIOBase` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase).